# My android app in play store says your device isn't compatible with the version, but when i try to install it from apk it is working

Tags: android

I have published an android application to the play store and in some devices it shows your device isnt compatible with the version. but when i used that same apk directly it is working well. any help will be appreciate.

this is the manifest file of the application.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.**************">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.*****************"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".AppIntroCalendar"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: whats te compile sdk version and minssdkversion? thats probably the prob.

Comment: minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: should i include them in manifest also. they are defined in gradle file also?

Comment: no they stay in gradle. whats sdk of the device?

Comment: samsung galxy s7 android noughat. API 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe those devices belong to small screens or xlarge screens as your declared in manifest

```
  <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

or maybe you should write this in manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

for more information https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: yes it is the problem. because of the device screen resolution changeble, samsung galaxy s7 & s8 series act as extra small or extra large sreens. thanks for your help.